# MYSQL - Saber los números faltantes dentro de una serie consecutiva?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas noches, comunidad de SO En Español.

Mi duda es la siguiente, tengo dos tablas.

```
id_cuenta|cuenta|
---------+------+
   1     | 1000 |
   2     | 2000 |
   3     | 3000 |
   4     | 4000 |
   5     | 5000 |

id_recibo|numero|
---------+------+
    1    | 1001 | 
    2    | 1100 |
    3    | 1200 |
    4    | 2011 |
    5    | 4800 |
```

El rango de número, inicia desde el valor del campo cuenta +1 y termina en cuenta+999. Es decir, el rango de recibos 1001-1999, pertenece a la cuenta 1000.

Lo que necesito saber, es cuáles son los números que faltaron dentro de ese rango, teniendo 1001,1100,1200; cómo puedo hacer para conseguir un listado de los demás números?

PD: Gracias por su tiempo y respuesta.

PD2: Hago las preguntas en éste foro y no en el que está en inglés, porque quiero contribuir a que siga crecido esta comunidad! :)

Comment: Quieres saber que numeros faltan o cuantos faltan?  Lo segundo es más trivial

Comment: que numeros. para saber cuales recibos son los faltantes

Comment: Y la respuesta que te di, ya la probaste ?, la manera de generar un rango de números que se utiliza en la respuesta, es con un **`CROSS JOIN`** (plano cartesiano) donde se multiplican todas las filas de una tabla por todas las filas de la otra tabla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una disculpa a las personas que no respondí, si meramente nuevo en esto y olvido que tengo que hacer el feedback.

@andrezi, gracias por tu respuesta.

Lo que hice, fue tomar el primer y el ultimo valor registrados en el campo 'recibo.numero', y crear un arreglo a partir de ello con la función range()

Algo como esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT MIN(numero)AS minnum,MAX(numero) AS maxnum FROM recibo";

$numr=array();

foreach($res_sql as $sql){          
 $numr=array_merge($numr,range($res_sql['minnum'],$res_sql['maxnum']));
}
```

Después de esto una consulta para sacar todos los numeros de recibo y hacer un arreglo con ellos:

```
$sql_recibo = "SELECT numero FROM recibo";

foreach ($res_recibo as $sql_recibo) {
 $arr_recibo[] = $res_recibo ['recibo']['numero'];
}
```

Al obtener esto, sólamente resta, hacer la comparar los arreglos:

```
$dif_recibos = array_diff($numr,$arr_recibo);
```

Y listo! obtenemos los números de recibo faltantes.

Espero le sirva a alguno, y vuelvo a pedir una disculpa por la tardanza! :D

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), que no se te olvide :) saludos.

Comment: Listo! @MauricioAriasOlave muchas gracias por el tip! :D

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches, men pues sin utilizar ciclos o estructuras de control, unicamente apunta de consultas, podrias hacer lo siguiente:

la estructura con la que realice las pruebas es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE cuenta ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
cuenta INT(10)
); 

CREATE TABLE recibo ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
numero INT(10)
); 


INSERT INTO `cuenta` (`cuenta`) 
VALUES (1000); 
INSERT INTO `cuenta` (`cuenta`) 
VALUES (2000); 
INSERT INTO `cuenta` (`cuenta`) 
VALUES (3000); 
INSERT INTO `cuenta` (`cuenta`) 
VALUES (4000); 
INSERT INTO `cuenta` (`cuenta`) 
VALUES (5000); 


INSERT INTO `recibo` (`numero`) 
VALUES (1001); 
INSERT INTO `recibo` (`numero`) 
VALUES (1100); 
INSERT INTO `recibo` (`numero`) 
VALUES (1200); 
INSERT INTO `recibo` (`numero`) 
VALUES (2011); 
INSERT INTO `recibo` (`numero`) 
VALUES (4800);
```

.

y la consulta que utilice para lograr el objetivo es la siguiente

```
SELECT x 
FROM(select (z*10000+th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) x from
(select 0 th union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
(select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
(select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C,
(select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) D,
(select 0 z union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) E
) rango
join(
select c.cuenta+1 as minimo,c.cuenta+999 as maximo,c.cuenta from cuenta c
) datos on rango.x >= datos.minimo and rango.x <= datos.maximo
where rango.x not in(
select numero from recibo)
order by rango.x
```

.

La tabla rango genera numeros del 1 hasta el 100.000,
el script de la tabla rango lo saque de la siguiente pagina 
[generar una secuencia en MySql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql) , en esa pagina explican como generar una secuencia segun la cantidad de numeros requeridos.

con el **`join`** se realiza una seleccion de los numeros que estan entre el rango minimo y el rango maximo de las cuentas.

con el **`where`** se excluyen los que ya han sido generados.

> **Nota**  :
>    En caso de que quieras saber los de una sola cuenta agregale al ***WHERE***
>   `datos.cuenta = 1000 --(el numero de la cuenta)`
>
> **Nota 2:**
>   todos los scripts los prove [aqui](http://sqltest.net/)

Comment: una disculpa! no me fije que no había puesto la respuesta. creo que no era lo que estaba buscando, o al menos no tuve el resultado esperado :(

Comment: ok, no hay problema, y ya lo pudiste conseguir ?, si es asi; que era? @MarcoLRam